# How to search in a given interval of a vector container

Tags: c++, vector, find

I want to search in a given interval (not a whole vector) of a vector container to see whether a user-specified integer is present or not. But I couldn't make it work. Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
int myints[] = { 10, 20, 30 ,40 };
vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+4);
vector<int>::iterator it, itLower, itUpper;
itLower = myvector.begin();
itUpper = myvector.begin();
advance(itLower, 1);
advance(itUpper, 2);

// iterator to vector element:
it = find (itLower, itUpper, 50);

if (it != myvector.end())
{  
   // Found
   cout << "Found it";
}
else
{ 
   // Not fount
   cout << "Not found it";
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just replace the line

```
if (it != myvector.end()) ...
```

by

```
if (it != itUpper) ...
```

If `find` does not find the item it returns the last element (which is in your case the end of your range and not of the complete vector). Note that the range is defined with `itUpper` exclusive.

Comment: Thank you! If the the last item (pointed by itUpper) happen to meet the search criteria. What should I do?

Comment: @GoldenLee As mentioned in my answer the last item is never included in your range. So if you want to have it included you have to define `itUpper` accordingly "one item later".

Comment: OK. I advance itUpper one more to include itself. Thank you!